# jfrog artifactory CLI deploy a jar in maven artifactory repo with inferred setting from jar

Tags: tfs, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I am using Visual Studio Artifactory deployer to deploy jar files built by maven to Artifactory maven repo. If I use maven artifactory plugin the jar file gets deployed to right folder structure and maven setting stay as per the jar but from CLI if i push the jar file, it only get deployed as a jar file to the folder I specify. For example

- Using CLI push a artifact.jar to target libs-snapshot/com/foo/bar
  gets file uploaded to libs-snapshot/com/foo/bar and artifactory has
  no information about jar version, group id , artifact id. I could not
  find any options on the CLI to specify those.
- While using Maven Artifactory plugin, a pushed jar ends up in
  libs-snapshot/com/foo/bar/artifact/version folder and maven
  properties stay intact

How do I achieve  same behaviour from CLI as maven artifactory plugin does.

Comment: @Andy-MSFT I see that you removed TFS tag, but the problem is kind of related to TFS build. I am using Atifactorydeployer step from TFS build and it uses Jfrong CLI to push the file to Artifactory. I wish Out of maven output it will deploy by extracting the maven layout into artifactory.

Answer (score 5):

Just to make sure, how do you use the CLI for the deployment? In order to have it deployed to Artifactory using the CLI, you will have to specify the right Maven coordinates. For example:

```
jfrog rt u mySnapshot-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar “libs-snapshot-local/path/to/folder/mySnapshot/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/”
```

This will deploy your snapshot file to Artifactory and Artifactory, base on your repository configuration will replace the “SNAPSHOT” with a timestamp.

If you meant that you want to deploy 5 different files, to 5 different paths and that you wish that the JFrog CLI to extract the maven layout and deploy by it, then this is not possible by using the CLI.

Comment: I am referring to the second part of your answer and wish CLI will support that. I am using Team Foundation Server's ArtifactoryDeployer step which essentially use Jfrong CLI to push files to Artifactory. I was hoping there was some way to extract the maven layout and deploy by it.

Comment: @gamepop As Ariel mentioned above, it's not possible by using the CLI, ArtifactoryDeployer step which essentially use Jfrong CLI, So, it will also hard to achieve that within TFS.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it @Andy-MSFT , is there a way from TFS to deploy other than using ArtifactoryDeployer , take output of maven build somehow for providing options to jfrog CLI.Currently I am using Maven Artifactory plugin to do the deploys but would like to decouple that from maven build as it takes away control and takes lot more time, not to mention we need to embed artifactory plugin in each pom file we have.